# Bean Not getting initialized in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I have a class which is creating and inserting data into a table.Please find my code below:

Class DBConnection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnection {
    public static Connection getDBConnection() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "expenseCalc";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "*********";
        String password = "*******";
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
}

SpringConfig.class

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class SpringConfig {
        @Bean("sqloperations")
        public SQLOperationJavaConfig sqLoperationJavaConfig() {
            DBConnection dbConnection=new AppJavaConfig<DBConnection>().getbean("dbconnection"); 
            return new SQLOperationJavaConfig(dbConnection);
        }
        @Bean("dbconnection")
        public DBConnection dbConnection() {
            return new DBConnection();
        }
    }

SQLOperationJavaConfig.class

public class SQLOperationJavaConfig {
    private DBConnection dbConnection;
    public SQLOperationJavaConfig(DBConnection dbConnection) {
        this.dbConnection=dbConnection;
    }
    private Connection conn;
    public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        conn = dbConnection.getDBConnection();
        String sql="drop table if exists dummy";
        String sql1 = "create table dummy (id int,name varchar(20))";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute(sql);
        statement.execute(sql1);
        System.out.println("Table Created!!");
    }

    public void insertData() throws SQLException {
        conn = dbConnection.getDBConnection();
        String sql = "insert into dummy values(12,'Sunny')";
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute(sql);
        System.out.println("Record Inserted!!");
    }
}
```

AppJavaConfig.java

```
public class AppJavaConfig<T> {
    static ApplicationContext context;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        SQLOperationJavaConfig sqLoperationJavaConfig = (SQLOperationJavaConfig) context.getBean("sqloperations");
        sqLoperationJavaConfig.createTable();
        sqLoperationJavaConfig.insertData();
    }
    public  T getbean(String beanName) {
        T t=(T) context.getBean(beanName);
        return t;
    }
}
```

When running this class i am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.src.springproj.AppJavaConfig.getbean(AppJavaConfig.java:17)
    at com.src.springproj.SpringConfig.sqLoperationJavaConfig(SpringConfig.java:10)
```

The getBean method is not returning the "dbconnection" Bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this getBean method..just change the initializer of SQLOperationsJavaConfig to the following:

```
return new SQLOperationJavaConfig(dbConnection());
```

Spring will look at the bean already created for the DBConnection

Answer (score 0):

Use **@autowired**.

```
@autowired
private DBConnection dbConnection;
```

Because The ***@Autowired*** annotation can be used to autowire bean on the setter method just like ***@Required*** annotation, constructor, a property or methods with arbitrary names and/or multiple arguments.

Comment: I only want to use JavaConfig and no autowiring .. Therefore i am not using @autowired annotation.